# What happens if you throw an Exception from inside UncaughtExceptionHandler?

Tags: java, exception

Not that it is a good design or it is something I am planning to do. Just curious, what happens if you throw an `Exception` from inside an `UncaughtExceptionHandler`? Is it possible to catch it somewhere?

Comment: rule of thumb: check the documentation of the class in question ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quote from [the method's Javadoc](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html#uncaughtException%28java.lang.Thread,%20java.lang.Throwable%29):

> Any exception thrown by this method will be ignored by the Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: Ignore exceptions!? That's really a design error if you would ask me

Comment: @Pacerier, well, suppose you designate a place for that (let's say, `HandlerForExceptionsThrownInUncaughtExceptionHandler`). What would you then answer to the inevitable question *"What happens if you throw an exception from inside `HandlerForExceptionsThrownInUncaughtExceptionHandler`?"*. And if you answer "well, let's designate a special handler for that..." ... do you get yet where this is heading to? :-)

Comment: Yes we print it out to a stream, or we call an **explicit** method `Ignore` if we do not wish to print it to a stream, instead of having thrown exceptions get ignored automatically

Comment: @Pacerier, you print it out, or call a method *from where*? You need to have a place to handle the exception first of all. Do you understand what `UncaughtExceptionHandler` is for?

Answer (score 0):

> Any exception thrown by this method will be ignored by the Java Virtual Machine.